# Ultra HD monitor with Macbook pro 13 mid 2014

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution

I have an Macbook pro 13 mid 2014. I want to connect an UHD monitor(3840x2160) and run it at 60Hz.

My thunderbolt's specs says that it can perform at 20 Gb/s.

My question: is it enough to run 3840x2160x60hz with mini displayport 1.2 cable? Is there anybody who did it successfully?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems like macbook pro 13 mid 2014 *theoretically can* serve  3840x2160x60hz, but apple won't support it.

There is a tool called SwitchResX, it can help maybe, but it requires System Integrity Protection to be disabled while install. I don't like the idea of disabling system security things in mac os, and i'm not even sure that it would work well.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple, for 13-inch Pro, only the early 2015 (or newer) versions support 4K@60Hz whether it's for single-stream or multi-stream.

I don't know if its possible unofficially. I've seen people get it to run at 52Hz.